# Mapped field not updating when parent record does

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

2013 On-Premise

Hello,

I have a parent record and a subgrid that can create a related record. When I create this related record several of the parent fields are mapped over to save the user double entry & mistakes.BTW the related record is being created via a quick create form.

Everything works great....at first.

If the parent record changes and the changes are saved. Then a new related record created the mapped fields DO NOT reflect the updated parent?

Further this behavior exist if there are NO related records or several.

Is my relationship not properly defined...i.e. needing cascading?...I thought that was just for cascading deletes???

Any input greatly appreciated

---

@Dave

My apologies...perhaps I have not been clear or I am not understanding you.

....If you need the previously mapped fields to change when the parent record values change....

This is where I am wondering if I am not being clear or understanding. This is happening on the "create" not existing records.

[image]

**So I thought perhaps incorrectly if I changed the parent record and then went to create a new related record it would get the new mapping?? BOLD just so text isn't lost between picts.**

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the parent, save it and the explicitly reload it (eg hit F5) before creating the second child record?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping functionality is only applied when the child record is created. Cascading only applies to events like deleting, sharing, unsharing, assigning, and re-parenting the parent record. Mapping is not involved in cascading at all. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309412.aspx

If you need the previously mapped fields to change when the parent record values change, this would best be addressed with a plugin. You may also consider making the child's mapped fields read only so user's don't think they can enter information in the child record's fields that get populated from the parent.